# Exporting To Excel in Php

Tags: php, html, excel, vba

I am trying to export one survey report into Excel sheet using php and it works fine at my localhost but when I hosted it is seemed to be just showing excel sheet instead of downloading. And I think it overrides the header in my code.

My code is here.

```
<?php
 ob_start();


        header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
```

How do I solve this problem with header.

Comment: this is not and excel question. it is not a VBA question either. please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try following code
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)

    header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);//filename with extension .xlsx
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: my server doesnot supports header.

Comment: try to add code ob_get_clean() after ob_start() header